# Group of buttons?

Tags: animation, button, android

I have a question - is there any way to define a few buttons as a 1 group, and make 1 animation that will start for this group, instead of making an separate animation start for each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them all in a ViewGroup and animate that. All children will be part of the animation. A ViewGroup is the base class for any layout class, that means you can use a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout or anything else that you find suitable.

Comment: @Tytanit Please keep the issues seperated, if you can't figure this out please open a new question. Otherwise it gets really hard for search engine users to find answers to their issues. Also please include the stacktrace *(do that always when you get a crash)*. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set to all buttons same onTouchListener, like:

```
 button1.setOnTouchListener(this);
 button2.setOnTouchListener(this);
 button3.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Of course your app needs to implement onTouchListener, and then you can write your onTouchListener:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

// write your code what you want your buttons to do

// You can also write some different codes for buttons by using id
if(v.getId() == button1.getId())
{
      //do something when button1 clicked...
}

}
```